# How to delete (remove) space between textboxes after remove some controls?

Tags: c#, button, textbox, panel

I'm new working with C# and I'm asking on here because I didn't find a solution searching in google and other questions on SO, I will explain what my example application does:

When I run it it display a form with a textbox by default, this textbox always will be shown, after type some text and press enter it will generate a new textbox and a new button (all the controls even the default textbox are inside a panel), and the new textboxes have the same functionality as the default textbox, when I click on the button generated next to its textbox it removes the button itself and the textbox but after that if I remove some random textboxes it leaves a space between these controls, how can reorganize this content to dont let space between them?

[image]

As you can see in the image, can you tell me how can fix this or give me an advice to achieve this? thank you, by the way this is the method I use to generate the buttons and textboxes

```
private void GenerarTextBox()
{
    panelContenedor.VerticalScroll.Value = panelContenedor.VerticalScroll.Minimum;

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = "Prueba " + id;
    tb.Name = "txtBox" + id;
    tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_Keydown);

    Button bt = new Button();
    bt.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    bt.Text = "X";
    bt.Name = "btnPrueba" + id;
    bt.Click += new EventHandler(ClickBotones);

    Point p = new Point(20, 30 * id);
    Point pb = new Point(130, 30 * id);

    tb.Location = p;
    bt.Location = pb;

    panelContenedor.Controls.Add(tb);
    panelContenedor.Controls.Add(bt);

    tb.Focus();
    id++;
}
```

And this to remove the textboxes and the buttons

```
private void ClickBotones(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button bt = sender as Button;

    string nombreBoton = bt.Name;
    string idBoton = nombreBoton.Substring(9);
    string nombreTextBox = "txtBox" + idBoton;

    foreach (Control item in panelContenedor.Controls.OfType<Control>())
    {
        if (item.Name == nombreTextBox)
        {
            panelContenedor.Controls.Remove(item);
            panelContenedor.Controls.Remove(bt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to change the location property?  That usually works to change the location

Comment: you can actually achieve the same implicit behavior with UserControls encapsulating the controls you're adding here, and the Docking property of those user controls inside the panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place your dynamic controls on a `FlowLayoutPanel`. Either directly or grouped together in a `Panel` or `UserControl`.

Set the `FlowDirection` property of the `FlowLayoutPanel` to `TopDown`. The `FlowLayoutPanel` will then arrange your controls automatically. You can also set the `WrapContents` property to `False` and `AutoScroll` to true to make the scroll bar appear.

Alternatively you can use `FlowDirection` = `LeftToRight`, place the text box and the button directly on the `FlowLayoutPanel` and let the child controls wrap (`WrapContents` = `True`). In the child controls, a new property `FlowBreak` appears. It can be set to `True` for the last control to appear in a row and let the next one wrap independently of the width of the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

You can also play with the `Margin` property of the child controls to control their layout in the `FlowLayoutPanel` as the `Location` property becomes useless.

The `FlowLayoutPanel` (as well as the `Panel`) is available in the Toolbox in the section "Containers".

Comment: I will try this and i will let you know.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt generate a scrollbar and generate the textboxes and buttons top to down and when reach the limit of the flowlayout it start to generate the news in the right

Comment: I have added more explanations to my answer. Play around with the `FlowDirection`, `WrapContents` and `AutoScroll` properties of the `FlowLayoutPanel` and with the `FlowBreak` and `Margin` properties of the child controls. To test their behavior it is easier to place some controls on the `FlowLayoutPanel` in the designer. Resize the panel manually to see what happens. I tested the 2 alternatives described in my answer (`FlowDirection` = `TopDown` and `LeftToRight`) and both work.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the controls, you need to do a recalc of the positions. So when you have added them in sequence, you can go with:

```
bool repos = false;
Point p;
foreach (Control item in panelContenedor.Controls.OfType<Control>())
    {
        if (repos)
        {
             Point tmp = item.Location;              
             item.Location = p;
             p = tmp;
        }


        if (item.Name == nombreTextBox)
        {
            panelContenedor.Controls.Remove(item);
            panelContenedor.Controls.Remove(bt);
            repos = true;
            p = item.Location;
        }

    }
```